# How to Join 3 tables, 1 from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that I'd like to join:

```
database1.dbo.Table1
Database1.dbo.table2
database2.dbo.table1
```

All of them will join on 'id'

I was thinking something like this, but I get a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Code:

```
Select *
From database1.dbo.table1 t1 
Left Join database1.dbo.table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
Left Join database2.dbo.table1 t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: and would you care to share the error message?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Show actual query not this oversimplified example

Comment: but the query posted is obviously not the same that you are using, so we won't be able to pinpoint the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try boxing the words, the reserve words "ID" or Database"1" might be the culprit, boxing is something like below.

```
Select *
    From [database1].[dbo].[table1] t1 
    Left Join [database1].[dbo].[table2] t2 
        on t1.[id] = t2.[id]
    left join database2.dbo.table1 t3 
        on t1.[id] = t3.[id]
```

Comment: This was exactly it.  the [] around the databases were the problem.  Thanks!